# How does Stream.Dispose(bool) get called by the Finalize method?

Tags: .net, finalizer, bufferedstream

The [Stream.Dispose(bool) docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143450%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say:

> This method is called by the public Dispose method and the Finalize method. [..]  Finalize invokes Dispose with disposing set to false.

However, neither [`Stream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs) nor its super class `MarshalByRefObject` have a destructor, and the destructor of `Object` is empty.

So how can `Stream.Dispose(bool)` get called by the `Finalize` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream` is a abstract class so you are guaranteed that at least one layer lower should be inherited. [In that inherited class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#1331) is where the finalizer exists.

I don't know their exact reasons, but one potentially could be is if [you don't need the finializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs) it is not forced on you due to the non zero overhead of having one, the biggest cost being your object likely wont be collected during the Gen 0 Garbage collection even if it is very short lived (see [this linked article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29365#Overhead) for details).

Comment: Interesting. Double checked with [`NetworkStream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs#664), same thing there.